# Mount a device to a partition that located in another device

Tags: centos, mount, partition, devices, home

```
[root@server]# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda3   8:3    0   10G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0    1K  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0  1.8T  0 part /home
sdb      8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
sdc      8:32   0  1.8T  0 disk
sdd      8:48   0  1.8T  0 disk
```

I need to mount the 3 disks ( sdb, sdc ,sdd ) in '/home/' that located in partition sda5, so I can get all usable storage in server ( 7.2 Tb ) in one directory. what I have to do first?

Should I start by creating a new partition in each of these 3 devices, then I can later mount the 3 partitions to /home? or I can directly mount the 3 devices in partition /home ?

Answer (score 1):

you must use lvm to do this.

1 - pvcreate

```
pvcreate /dev/sda5
pvcreate /dev/sdb
...
```

2 - vgcreate (this create a "common space" for all volumes)

```
vgcreate vghome /dev/sda5 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

3 - lvcreate (this add all together)

```
lvcreate -n lvhome -l 100%FREE
```

4 - filesystem must be formated

```
mkfs -t ext3 /dev/vghome/lvhome
```

5 - mount

```
mount /dev/vghome/lvhome /home
```

please note

- all previous content of `/home` will be erased.
- a failure of a single disk will make `/home` unavailable

to procedd `unmount /dev/sda5` (you may need to comment `/etc/fstab` and reboot).
beware `pvcreate` will destroy (after confirmation) all data in `/home`.

Comment: I don't have LVM . It doesn't work without LVM ?

Comment: you have zfs ? which zfs will give you a path ?

Comment: @Zorba There are other ways than LVM, but LVM is the easiest and most flexible method, so you should use LVM. LVM is a standard Linux feature, so you do have LVM if you have CentOS or any other Linux distribution.

Answer (score -2):

- You should create partitions on all the new drives by using either fdisk or gdisk utility.

-then format them by using a mkfs command (e.g., mkfs -t ext4 /dev/disk1).

- then mount them with mount command (e.g., mount -t ext4 /dev/disk1 /mnt/mount).
- Finally, make sure you add your new drive entries to /etc/fstab file, so they get mounted automatically upon reboot.

Comment: I fail to see how this will **add** disk space as OP request.